# Incorrect polynomial interpolation?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I have tried to play around with the Lagrange form of a polynomial. I want to interpolate the points $(-1,6), (2, 8), (5,-2)$. I have done this in Maple and plotted the graph. The problem is that I seem to get an incorrect function:
[image]
As you can see, the graph does interpolate the points $(-1,6)$ but not the two others. Can you spot what is wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure about Maple because I have never used it and there isn't a free online terminal for it, but this works fine on [Sage](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxVjrsOgzAMRXckvoMEjGq76kOK_CVVh6owIIUGAUPcr294dGCyfXSu7YhSk4sk7CLLJc8U5eqU5O6UpeY88yjGxDqSLZfC1p7SjDvAlSSLNgsPFu2A_hYfLNos3gGvJM-G4FUGH2ajWHqslEpPlXLpGUyE-gw3C9p3H0mt9q8ohCnWhHmSIXSfeTKP9Bko2uQTKC2VQdk-4R18GKUY26aAqfu2W3Y5WS0LfmQLSG8=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

Comment: Ok, I installed Maple on my machine to test your code. It seems that implied multiplication is not interpreted as usual multiplication but rather "apply function" (which I thought was function composition, but that doesn't seem to be the case, for eg, $(x+1)(x^3)$ is interpreted as extracting the $x$ from $x^3$ and applying the map $x\mapsto x+1$, so it's just the add by one map). You need to explicitly specify multiplication in both numerator and denominator in your definitions of $l_0,l_1,l_2$ by using the `*` key on your keyboard.

Comment: Looking at it again, I think it does function composition, just not in the general sense. For example, with the map $x\mapsto (x+1)(x^3)$ evaluated at say $x=2$, Maple interprets this as first calculating the map $x\mapsto x+1$ at $x=2$ which is the constant map $x\mapsto 3$ and then applies it to $x^3$, which gives you $3$